# spark.executor.instances over spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = True

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working in a Spark project using MapR distribution where the dynamic allocation is enabled. Please refer to the below parameters :

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled         true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled           true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors    0
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors    20
spark.executor.instances                2
```

As per my understanding spark.executor.instances is what we define as --num-executors while submitting our pySpark job.

I have following 2 questions :

1. if I use `--num-executors 5` during my job submission will it overwrite `spark.executor.instances 2` config setting?
2. what is the purpose of having `spark.executor.instances` defined when dynamic allocation min and max executors are already defined?

Answer (score 1):

`spark.executor.instances` basically is the property for static allocation. However, if dynamic allocation is enabled, the initial set of executors will be at least equal to  `spark.executor.instances`.

It wont get overwritten in the config setting, when you set --num-executors.

Extra read: [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more parameter which is

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors
```

it takes the value of `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors`. If `spark.executor.instances` 
is defined and its larger than the minExecutors then it will take the value of the initial executors.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, but my question was regarding spark.executor.instances. If dynamic allocation is defined what is the use of having spark.executor.instances.

Comment: If dynamic allocation is defined then in enterprise applications number of executors are not required to be defined at all. the dynamic allocation property will assign the executors between the ranges of min and max executors. But in case its defined and greater than the min executors property then it will take at least that number of executors for the run.